# Retrieving between > < soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve those informations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEV1g.png

from this website: https://www.skiinfo.fr/vorarlberg/golm/station-de-ski.html

Below is the code I have so far. I succesfuly find the element on the page, retrieved the name of each element but I cannot find how to retrieve the values (30,50,20,14,44,9.2,44) as there's no identification possible, only the fact that it is between "> <". (Must I say I'm quite new to this!)

```
link="https://www.skiinfo.fr/vorarlberg/golm/station-de-ski.html"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, "html.parser")
div = soup.find('ul', {"class" : "rt_trail circles"})

children = div.findChildren("li" , recursive=False)
for child in children:
    print(child.p.string)
```

which is giving me:

```
Pistes vertes
Pistes bleues
Pistes rouges
Pistes noires
Pistes
Km pistes
Snowparks
Piste la plus longue
Domaine skiable
Neige de culture
Canons à neige (km pistes)
```

Could someone explain me what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for child in children:
    print(child.p.string)
```

is equivalent to

```py
for child in children:
    print(child.find("p").string)
```

so you are assuming that your values are inside the **first** `p`-tag inside each `child`, which is clearly not true. Instead, you can search for the first `p`-tag with the css class `value`:

```py
for child in children:
    print(child.find("p", class_="value").text)
```

This yields

```
30%
50%
20%
14
44 km
9.2 km
44 km
```

Can you go on from here?

Comment: This is what I needed it is perfect, thank you !